# push an array of references to any number of hashes [ perl ]

Tags: perl

suppose i have an array:

```
@array = {
'A'    =>    "",
'B'    =>    0,
'C'    =>    0,
'D'    =>    0,
};
```

i can add an element by:

```
$count = 0;
$array[$count]->{A} = "abcd";
$array[$count]->{B} = 789;
$array[$count]->{C} = 456;
$array[$count]->{D} = 123;
```

and another element,

```
$count++;
$array[$count]->{A} = "efgh";
$array[$count]->{B} = 111;
$array[$count]->{C} = 222;
$array[$count]->{D} = 333;
```

how can i add elements to @array using push?

Comment: As the folks below pointed out, you're confusing arrays with hash references.  Take a look at `perldoc perlref` (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: while `perlref` is good, I prefer [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut) since I think it is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That first structure you have is a `hash reference`, not an `array`. You cannot add values to a `Hash` via `push`. `push` will only operate on an `array`. If you wish to add a value to a `hash reference` you will need to either use `->` notation or dereference.

```
$hash->{ 'key' } = $val;  // ->
%{ $hash }{ 'key' } = $val;  //dereferencing
```

If you have an `array reference` inside of a `hash reference` you can access it in the same manner as above.

```
$hash->{ 'array key' }->[$index] = $val;
@{ $hash->{ 'array key' }}[$index] = $val;
```

---

As for creating an array you use `(` and `)` like so

```
my @array = ( "One", "Two", "Three" );
```

Another option is to use the `qw()` shortcut like so

```
my @array = qw(one two three);
```

Additionally you can create an array by reference using `[` and `]`

```
my $array_ref = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

Finally to push a value to an array you use `push`

```
push(@array, $value);
```

Though, push being a list context function can be written sans parens.

```
push @array, $value;
```

Comment: ok, you've made it clear.
I can now push an element to a hash reference like this:


     $array->{A} = "QWERTY";
     $array->{B} = 000;
     $array->{C} = 999;
     $array->{D} = 888;

     push @array, $array;
thanks for helping :)

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong.
well, i think @array is an array of pointers to a hash.

Comment: It's an array of pointers to any number of hashes. Each index of the array can point to its own or a previously seen hash.

Comment: It's not an array of pointers, it's an array of references. Pointers and references are not the same thing. Perl doesn't have pointers, it has arrays.